# Is is possible to change the default appPool folder location when using ApplicationPoolIdentity in IIS 7.5?

Tags: iis-7.5, application-pools

I understand in IIS 7.5, the default Application Pool identity is ApplicationPoolIdentity and on accessing the Web site, it creates a temporary folder under C:\inetpub\temp\appPools with the Web site related configuration.

My question is: Is it possible to change the default folder location i.e. C:\inetpub\temp\appPools for ApplicationPoolIdentity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer.. [KB 949348](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949348)